# How should I send JWT token in axios GET request?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, axios

I'm new to Vue.js and want to make a request in a component to a restricted api:

```
  computed: {
    token () {
      return this.$store.getters.getToken; 
    },
   ...

created () {
         axios
        .get( this.BASE_URL + '/profile/me')
        .then( res => {
                    this.profile = res.data;
                    console.log('profile is:', res.data);

          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))            
    },
```

The problem is that I don't know how to include the token into the request header. So not surprisingly I get `401` error in response.

And when I try

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = this.token;
```

before the get request I receive `OPTIONS /profile/me` instead of `GET /profile/me` in the server logs.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Axios `get()` request accept two parameter. So, beside the url, you can also put JWT in it.

```
axios.get(yourURL, yourConfig)
.then(...)
```

In your case `yourConfig` might be something like this

```
yourConfig = {
   headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + yourJWTToken
   }
}
```

Also you can read about what you can put in your config here https://github.com/axios/axios.
Just search for **"Request Config"**

Comment: I get `OPTIONS /profile/me 200` in serve log. and no GET request . Also Browser complains about  ` Authorization is not allowed ` despite the fact that I have this in expess: `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"); ...` in express settings.

Comment: Instead of changing your server behavior, you can fake the domain by installing this extension on your local machine.(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi). Config your server to accept request from different domain lead to some kind of CSRF attack.
Also, remember to turn off that extension after developing.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, try like -

```
let JWTToken = 'xxyyzz';
 axios
    .get(this.BASE_URL + '/profile/me', { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${JWTToken}`} })
    .then(res => {
       this.profile = res.data;
       console.log('profile is:', res.data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: I get this error: `Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:3000/profile/me: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`. Any ideas?

Comment: When we use custom request headers we will get a CORS preflight. We need to reply to that CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS headers to make this work. like - ` { res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"); `

Comment: I know. I have express `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    
  next();
});` but still get the error. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: if you using webpack with vue app, then try this - https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853#issuecomment-374846375 it will solve the problem by configuring proxy to avoid CORS

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to put that. snippet. I've created the app using vue.cli. And there is a `webpack.config.js` in `/node_modules/@vue/cli-service` but when I put there `"devServer":{
  "proxy": {
    "/": {
    "target": 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    "pathRewrite": { '^/': '' },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false
    }
  }
}` still get the same error after vue server reload. What could be wrong here?